# vuetify v-data-table ignores dense property

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a vuetify v-data-table widget that displays data. Currently the data shown uses too much space (rows have a lot of padding) so I use the dense prop. I add the property dense (like that, not dense='true') to the table opening tag but nothing happens. The display stays wide and the property is ignored.

Tried to remove all props except the items prop:

```html
<v-data-table
      dense
      :items="results"
>
```

makes no difference. dense is ignored.

I currently have this:

```
<v-flex xs12>
     <v-data-table
         dense
         :headers="headers"
         :items="results"
          :disable-initial-sort="true"
         :pagination.sync="pagination"
         class="elevation-1 results-table"
         @update:pagination="updatePagination($event)"
  />
>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with `dense` property not working for `v-data-table`.

In my case it was the `v-checkbox` added to `v-data-table` that was causing the `dense` prop not to work. When using checkboxes inside `v-data-table` use `v-simple-checkbox` as explained here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#simple-checkbox

Answer (score 0):

ok, the 'elevated-1' class was overwitten causing the dense prop also to have no effect... /: